# Access website hosted on local vagrant vm

Tags: macos, ubuntu, vagrant

I am trying to make a local dev environment so I can work on my site matthewfedak.co.uk.

I am using vagrant and virtual box.

Here is my vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "lucid32"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "localhost.sh"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host:4567, guest: 80
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 3306, guest: 3306   
    config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/mfedak/sites", "/var/www/vhosts", :owner => "www-data", :group => "www-data"
end
```

Here is my /etc/hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
#127.0.0.1      localhost
#255.255.255.255        broadcasthost
#::1            localhost
#fe80::1%lo0    localhost
127.0.0.1:4567  matthewfedak.co.uk
127.0.0.1:4567  www.matthewfedak.co.uk
```

Here is my vhost for the site in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/matthewfedak.co.uk

vagrant@lucid32:~$ sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/matthewfedak.co.uk

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin info@matthewfedak.co.uk
        ServerName matthewfedak.co.uk
        ServerAlias www.matthewfedak.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/matthewfedak.co.uk/httpdocs/
        ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/matthewfedak.co.uk/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/matthewfedak.co.uk/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It sounds simple but I am getting bored of toying with this now. I have setup lots of Ubuntu servers before so don't think that its to with that, just to do with getting the host / remote to communicate.

Comment: Not a StackOverflow question. Try [serverFault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: A firewall or listen port error in the VM maybe?

Comment: I am using a proxy plugin for chrome canary called SwitchySharp and if I browse with proxy IP: 127.0.0.1, Port: 4567 it works fine. But the site matthewfedak.co.uk may need to pull images in from other sites and I don't want the proxy to apply to these. I can make specific exceptions based on regex's in SwitchySharp but I don't ideally want that. I just want my site url to be mapped to my local version through the host file, everything else from web. I did it for years on windows no problem.

Answer (score 2):

By default Vagrant uses NAT mode for networking, which requires a lot of port mappings if you are testing a full stack. What's more, due to the limitation of VirtualBox's NAT mode:

> Forwarding host ports < 1024 impossible:
>
> On Unix-based hosts (e.g. Linux, Solaris, Mac OS X) it is not possible to bind to ports below 1024 from applications that are not run by root. As a result, if you try to configure such a port forwarding, the VM will refuse to start.

That's why you use port 4567 on host, right?

Now, **Root cause** is in your `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1:4567  matthewfedak.co.uk
127.0.0.1:4567  www.matthewfedak.co.uk
```

The `hosts` file is a simple text file that associates IP addresses with hostnames, one line per IP address. It does NOT work with port numbers.

To work around, consider using bridged mode or vagrant's [private network](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) so that you can access the guest using an IP address instead of using host's loopback.

Comment: "On Unix-based hosts (e.g. Linux, Solaris, Mac OS X) it is not possible to bind to ports below 1024 from applications that are not run by root.". This is not true. On Solaris you can assign the `PRIV_NET_PRIVADDR` privilege (allows to bind to a privileged port) to any user and then he will be able to bind to port < 1024. However in Solaris it is more common to assign this privilege to a SMF service (a daemon if you like) rather than to a user. In general the statement "you need to be root to ..." is something that comes from Linux world. It doesn't apply in Solaris.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I think VirtualBox dudes need to update the VirtualBox [user manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nat-limitations), see NAT limitations part.

Comment: Yes, you see statements like that all over the place. I guess it is just simpler to write it as if Solaris also requires root priv for this. Then you can write statements like : "On Unix/Linux you need to be root to ..." without elaborating too much. Truth be told this ability did not come to Solaris until 2005 (with Solaris 10).

Comment: Well, this is half an answer. Which is it? Bridged mode or a private network?